# How do I select all a tags with href starts with http and does not contain an element with tag img OR class that begins with "fa"?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, font-awesome, attr

Trying to use Font Awesome to add internal link indicators to my page. Current CSS:

```
a[href^="https"]::after > :not(img, [class^="fa"]) {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: " ";
}
```

Yes, I'm trying to select an element depending on whether it has a certain type of child. That is, if  does not have a child of  or , add an Font Awesome icon after

Comment: Are you trying to select an element depending on whether it has a certain type of child? You can’t as such. Could you describe more what effect you want without thinking about what the solution might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
a[href^="https"]:not(img, [class^="fa"])::after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: " ";
}
```

Comment: Adds the icon after <a>, but also those elements where <a> has a child of <img>